# Firebase: access child from UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in Java and I have a child within my database named "Chatmessages" with a list of users (who have started a chat) This list contains the UID's of those users. And within my database I also have a "Users" child, which contain information all the users. How use the "Chatmessages" with the list of UID's but get the information from the corresponding UID's from "Users".

[image: Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your database structure, to achieve this you need to query your database twice. Assuming that both nodes, `Chatmessages` and `Users` are direct childs of your Firebase root, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference chatIdRef = rootRef.child("Chatmessages").child(chatId);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Boolean onlineStatus = dataSnapshot.child("onlineStatus").getValue(Boolean.class);
                    String status = dataSnapshot.child("nstatusame").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", image + " / " + name + " / " + onlineStatus + " / " + status);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
chatIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Using this code, you'll get user's data only from a specific chat. Please see that i have used in the first `DatabaseReference` a variable named `chatId`, which is actually the id of a particular chat. As an example, in your screen-shot is 5kAiGg7zu...

Comment: Thank you! do you know how I would do the same thing but to load a list of users.

Comment: You should do in the same way. Add a listener and query only for the users.

Comment: public void loadUserList() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(
                User.class,
                R.layout.userlist_layout,
                UserViewHolder.class,
                chatIdRef


        )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question you want to get the chat messages of a specific user. In order to do that you need to have access on uid of the specific User. One way to save it, is when the user sign in or sign up get the key and save it on SharedPreferences.

Then after you have the key you can run a firebase query to retrieve the chat messages of this user. You got 3 options of what firebase listener you are going to use. ValueEventListener which will you give a data snapshot of all data, ChildEventListener which will return one child at the time and SingleValueEvenetListener which will you give a data snapshot of all data only for once.

```
Query queryChatMessages = mDatabase.child("Chatmessages").child(uid);
queryChatMessages.addChildEventListener("your listener");
```